# Use .htaccess to append query string to URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I need to do something like this: URLs http://domain.com/view.php?show=my_article_name should be resirected to http://domain.com/my_article_name/ How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, there exists a million resources for this here on Stack Overflow, and on the wider Internet. Please always search first. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I found only this version, but it does not fit me: `RewriteRule ^blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? view.php?&show=$1 [L]`, ie redirect to http://domain.com/blog/my_article_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+view\.php\?show=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /view.php?show=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Very rare for someone to want to redirect an SEO-unfriendly URL to an SEO-friendly one, usually it's the other way around so please be sure that you want:

```
http://domain.com/view.php?show=xyz   =>   http://domain.com/xyz/
```

And not the more common:

```
http://domain.com/xyz                 =>   http://domain.com/view.php?show=xyz
```

You'd use something like this to capture the query string and pass it to the URL (I've added `R=301` to flags but if you don't want a permanent redirect, replace this with `R`):

```
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}    ^show=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule   ^view.php$         %1/            [NC,R=301,L]
```

Untested as I'm not currently running Apache, but if it helps but isn't right please give me the working code to fix my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I got 404.

Comment: Check access.log and error.log, Apache issues usually easy to debug.

Comment: @RedOctober - Edited, tell me if that fixes it. NOTE: While testing you may want to use `R` instead of `R=301` as some browsers cache 301s for a long time.

Comment: I'm still have 404 :(

Comment: What's in `access.log` and `error.log`? You need to provide more information for me to help any further as I don't have Apache running here.